# ElasticSearch "Word in Word" Tokenizer/Filter

Tags: symfony, filter, elasticsearch, tokenize

I'm using the snowball analyzer to find a product called "cherries" if you search for "cherry". Everything works like a charm, but now I want to be able to search for "word in words".

For example, if you search for "berries", the server should find "cranberries", "blackberries", and so on. The same result should occur for "berry".

Which filter/tokenizer I have to use for this? I'm new to ElasticSearch.

This is my config now:

```
settings:
    index:
        analysis:
            analyzer:
                index_analyzer:
                    type: "snowball"
                    language: English
```

Comment: I highly recommend you install this plugin either within Elasticsearch or run on a webserver - https://github.com/polyfractal/elasticsearch-inquisitor ... This will allow you to break down tokens using the various analyzers that Elasticsearch offers.

Comment: Did you try using FOSElasticaBundle which is for using ElasticSearch in Symfony? You can use wild cards and you have lots of varieties to filer or search

Comment: Yes, I'm using FOS Elastica for this. I dont want to use wild cards, because they scale badly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the nGram Tokenizer for that.